# Not able to use phonegap application when i connect my blackberry device in USB mode

Tags: cordova, blackberry

I have a phonegap application(using HTML5 and jQueryMobile) working fine on my blackberry device. I connected my blackberry device to PC in USB(or sync) mode, Open phone memory in PC and start using the application. I get the following error displayed!!

unkonwn error Error:SECURITY_ERR DOM exception 18

Application also started throwing SQl Exception 1 when my application tries to make db transaction.

One more if I select "charge only" mode connection to PC this error doesn't happen!

I have no clue why this happens.Can some one help me please.

Answer (score 3):

I have not come across this error myself but i saw a post saying that this is because the device cannot write to the memory card when device is plugged in (or somthing like that). This is why it works when you are in  "charge only" mode. This error is completely normal. Hope this inlightens you a bit, like i said this is what i read.

Comment: Thanks for your response. yes could be. But you will see this issue for sure when you connect BB to PC in Sync mode and open phone memory on the PC.